# Configuring TFS to prevent developers from seeing projects

Tags: version-control, tfs, alm

I'm new to TFS 2012 and switching from SourceGear Vault.  In Vault you can set permission on folders so it's easy to give John Doe permissions to a specific set of folders.  I'm not sure how to do this in TFS 2012. Let me further explain my scenario.

I have a folder on my hard drive we'll call C:\MyCompany

Under the root "MyCompany" folder is:

```
App1.Client
App1.Library
App1.Data
App2.Client
App2.Utilities
CompanyShared.Utilities
CompanyShared.Windows
CompanyShared.Logging
```

I want developer 1 to see and use App1.* and CompanyShared.*

I want developer 2 to see App2.* and CompanyShared.Utilities

How can I configure this to ensure different developers (sub-contractors) only see what they are assigned to develop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Source Code Explorer and right click on each folder and you will Advanced, underneath that is Security. From there you can assign permissions